# MySQL: Accumulate occurrences of each specific value in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, accumulate

I want to get a field that contains the # number of occurrence of a value in a field.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `events` (`country`) VALUES
('es'), ('fr'), ('uk'),
('uk'), ('es'), ('uk'),
('fr'), ('it'), ('es'),
('es'), ('it'), ('uk'),
('fr'), ('es'), ('de')
```

That is, given [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb2/13), I want to add a field `accumulated` to the results, containing the **number of times that a value in field `country` has appeared until that row**.

```
SELECT e.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events` AS e2
 WHERE e2.country = e.country) AS times
FROM `events` AS e

ID  | COUNTRY | TIMES | ACCUMULATED
----+---------+-------+------------
1   | es      | 5     | 1
2   | fr      | 3     | 1
3   | uk      | 4     | 1
4   | uk      | 4     | 2
5   | es      | 5     | 2
6   | uk      | 4     | 3
7   | fr      | 3     | 2
8   | it      | 2     | 1
9   | es      | 5     | 3
10  | es      | 5     | 4
11  | it      | 2     | 2
12  | uk      | 4     | 4
13  | fr      | 3     | 3
14  | es      | 5     | 5
15  | de      | 1     | 1
```

I guess that is some kind of conditional `SUM`, but I am not sure how.

Comment: You wouldn't normally store this kind of thing as it can be easily calculated 'on-the-fly'. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb2/62

Comment: @Strawberry maybe I confused you by using 'add'; I obviously didn't mean adding that field to the table, but to the resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sum is necessary. I think you just need second condition "until that row":

```
select e.*,
       (select count(*) from `events` as e2
        where e2.country = e.country
       ) as times,
       (select count(*) from `events` as e3
        where e3.country = e.country AND e3.id <= e.id
       ) as accumulated
from `events` as e
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f6bb2/44

Comment: This solution will be s-l-o-w on larger data sets :-(

Comment: Yes, that is true. If response times drop below acceptable limit you should consider storing "times" and "accumulated" in the table and calculate it on insert.

Comment: ...or just switch to one of the methods I suggested above ;-)